My app often fails to access the network （iOS，Objective-c）
My app often fails to access the network (other apps on the device can access the network normally), and restarting the app is also ineffective. I need to open and close the flight mode to restore the app's network
I used to suspect the background refresh was the cause, but removing the background refresh still occasionally causes this problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
